# Adding values dynamically to different columns of datatable from c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Input through ASP.net & C#

```
    productname      group         quantity          
         A             x             2
         B             y             4 
         A             x             3
```

Output in data-table:

```
        productname      x             y
          A              5             0 
          B              0             4
```

I just want to add values, through sql queries. I want to update the data in data table from C# coding. Could you please someone help me to solve.

Comment: How does 3 become 5? (Or am I lost?)

Comment: first am adding 2 for product A, then add 3 more for the same product with the same group. So the values should update in result

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional summing in a `group by`:

```
select productname,
       sum(case when group = 'x' then quantity else 0 end) as x,
       sum(case when group = 'y' then quantity else 0 end) as y
from tablename
group by productname
```

Note that `group` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit it as `"group"`.